# R with ggplot2: Keeping certain rows of a dataframe when making scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

A third week into my R class (please be patient with me even if it seems obvious where went wrong!), and I am struggling with a homework problem with using the R ggplot2 library. Using the built in diamonds data frame, the problem is to make a scatter plot regression line for log (carat) and log (price), but plotting **only for the Fair and Ideal cut diamonds**.

[This is what the plot is supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D0uS.png)

[image]

A quick background, the 3 variables in question here are carat (num), cut (Fair, Good, Very Good, Premium, Ideal), and price (int).

I start with the following code:

```
set.seed(123) 
d <- ggplot(diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds),5000),] #this was provided to us in the homework

d + geom_point(aes(x = log(carat), y = log(price), colour = cut) +
  labs(title = 'Regression line for Fair and Ideal Cut Diamonds') +
  stat_smooth(aes(x = log(carat), y = log(price), colour = cut), method = "gam")
```

[Here's what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grBum.png)

[image]

Now, I know this is incorrect, because "colour = cut" shows ALL the cuts, but I only want "Fair" and "Ideal". The professor hinted that we should try diamonds$cut%in%c(...), and so I tried it in many different ways. One of the latest (wrong) code is:

```
d + geom_point(aes(x = log(carat), y = log(price), colour = diamonds[diamonds$cut%in%c("Fair","Ideal")]), alpha = 0.5) +
 labs(title = 'Regression line for Fair and Ideal Cut Diamonds') +
 stat_smooth(aes(x = log(carat), y = log(price), colour = diamonds[diamonds$cut%in%c("Fair","Ideal")]), method = "gam")
```

I continue to get error messages regardless of where I tried to subset the diamonds$cut (e.g., Length of logical index vector for '[' must equal number of columns, Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (5000):colour).

How do I extract just the Fair and Ideal cut to make this graph?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should `filter` your data first. See this tutorial https://suzan.rbind.io/2018/02/dplyr-tutorial-3/

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to define the `data` argument to `ggplot2` prior to declaring it within the `ggplot` argument, although I'm not sure how to filter the `cut` column when it is specified as a mapping variable in `aes(colour = cut)`. Although the plot doesn't appear exactly as it should according to your post if that matters at this point. Hopefully this helps.

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)
z <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds),5000),]
z <- z[z$cut %in% c("Fair", "Ideal"),]

d <- ggplot(data = z) +
  geom_point(aes(x = log(carat), y = log(price), colour = cut), alpha = 0.5) +
  labs(title = 'Regression line for Fair and Ideal Cut Diamonds') +
  stat_smooth(aes(x = log(carat), y = log(price), colour = cut), method = "gam")
d
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Why not to stick with the `tidyverse` and use `filter()` instead of the archaic way of subsetting the data via `[,]`?;)

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Use subset() to subset the data. One modification is to get exactly as your graph is changing the method to 'auto' in stat_smooth so the line will follow the data points.
The chart can't be same always as we are doing random sampling.

```
library(ggplot2)

df<-diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds),50000),]

subset(df,cut%in%c("Fair","Ideal"))->df_fair_ideal

ggplot(df_fair_ideal,aes(x=log(carat),y=log(price),color=cut),alpha=0.5)+
  labs(title = 'Regression line for Fair and Ideal Cut Diamonds') +
  geom_point()+xlim(min(log(df_fair_ideal$carat)),max(log(df_fair_ideal$carat)))+
  stat_smooth(method = "auto",se=T)
```

[image]